# How to close Netbeans html debug Chrome connection when silent mode is on?

Tags: html, debugging, google-chrome, netbeans

As I stated in the title, how does one close (temporarily disables) debugging session connection Netbeans 7.4 with Chrome browser. The browser has flag `#silent-debugger-extension-api` turned on and Netbeans connector extension installed. Sometimes I have to turn off debugging because Netbeans CSS window does not show browser native styles, which is confusing. Thank you from the mountain! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply open Chrome Developer Tools in given page. It terminates session between NetBeans and Chrome because only 1 degbugger can debug page - either Chrome Dev Tools or NetBeans. Once you close Chrome Developer Tools, re-run your project/file from NetBeans to get debugging with NetBeans back.